# Substrate Pallet::Call, unpack the Pallet:Call's content

Tags: substrate-node-template, extrinsic, call, validation

In default [Substrate-Node-Template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) I want to make some actions inside **validate_transaction** function which is located in runtime/src/lib.rs:

```
fn validate_transaction(
            source: TransactionSource,
            tx: <Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic,
            block_hash: <Block as BlockT>::Hash,
        ) -> TransactionValidity {...}
```

What I'm trying to do, is to take [tx](https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/6.0.0/sp_runtime/generic/struct.UncheckedExtrinsic.html) parameter and extract Call Value by:

```
            if tx.signature.is_none() {
                //Do Something
            }else {
                let function_result = &tx.function;
            };
```

This function_result variable has type 'Call' with value of

*Call::Mypallet(Call::my_custom_function { content: [123, 32, 9, 34, 110, 101, 116]}*
I want to get content as a final result. But can not somehow communicatie with "Call" type. How can i extract the content field from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at code snippets in Substrate like this one:

```rust
fn test_blocks(
    genesis_config: &GenesisConfig,
    executor: &NativeElseWasmExecutor<ExecutorDispatch>,
) -> Vec<(Vec<u8>, Hash)> {
    let mut test_ext = new_test_ext(genesis_config);
    let mut block1_extrinsics = vec![CheckedExtrinsic {
        signed: None,
        function: Call::Timestamp(pallet_timestamp::Call::set { now: 0 }),
    }];
    block1_extrinsics.extend((0..20).map(|i| CheckedExtrinsic {
        signed: Some((alice(), signed_extra(i, 0))),
        function: Call::Balances(pallet_balances::Call::transfer {
            dest: bob().into(),
            value: 1 * DOLLARS,
        }),
    }));
    let block1 =
        construct_block(executor, &mut test_ext.ext(), 1, GENESIS_HASH.into(), block1_extrinsics);

    vec![block1]
}
```

Basically the onion should look like this:

1. The "runtime Call" enum will have an item `Call::PalletName`
2. That item will have entries which match the "pallet Call" enum, which will have items like `Call::extrinsic_name`. You can differentiate the runtime and pallet call by accessing the pallet call like: `pallet_name::Call::extrinsic_name`.
3. From there you have access to the parameters of the call.

So, here is some pseudo code:

```rust
fn extract_content_from_call(call: Call) -> Option<ContentType> {
    let pallet_call: pallet_name::Call = match call {
        Call::MyPallet(pallet_call) => pallet_call,
        _ => return None,
    };

    let content: ContentType = match pallet_call {
        pallet_name::Call::my_custom_function { content } => content,
        _ => return None,
    };

    Some(content)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can match on `tx.function`:

```rust
            match tx.function {
                Call::Balances(..) => {
                    Executive::validate_transaction(source, tx, block_hash)
                }
                _ => {
                    todo!("");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So, as you can see, i added an example. So, can you advise on the next step to extract data? My final step is to decode the data this Extrinsic has. If i use match tx.function {Call::Balances(..)) how would i get into the next layer of the call(pls. see the description) to reach the Call::my_custom_function.content?